# Show select2 "pillboxes" in an input separate from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to show the selected options from a select2 dropdown in a separate input and then remove the option from the dropdown.

So far the approach I've been taking is setting the dropdown as a normal select and then on a click, adding the value of the clicked on option as a new selected option for the "selected options input".

This has been giving me issues when I want to remove a selected option from the input though as I haven't been able to find an effective way to add the removed option back to the original select and other aspects of the select have been really janky.

To quote Shark Tank entrepreneurs: "There has to be a better way!"

Below is a mockup of what I'm trying to do and my existing code what I'm trying to do:

[image: mockup of select2]

```js
function initCodeSelectTwo() {
  $('#codeDropdown').select2({
    width: "100%",
    ajax: {
      url: 'urlOne',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      data: data
    }
  })

  var codeSelector = $('#codeSelector');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'urlOne' // controller method gets options already assigned to item
  }).then((data) => {
    var option = new Option(data.Code, data.Code, true, true);
    codeSelector.trigger({
      type: 'select2: select',
      params: {
        data: data
      }, 
      multiple: true
    });
  })
}

function UpdateDropdown() {
  // using click instead of change because the dropdown has been configured to not close on click
  $('#codeDropdown').on('click', 'option', function(event) {

    var option = $(this).val();
    $('select box option[value="' + option + '"]').remove();
    $("#codeInput").append('<option value="' + option + '">' + option + '</option>');
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I wasn't able to find anything in the select2 documentation for this and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to program it using the events provided by select2. In your case, the `select2:select` event will capture the selected option which you can then program to show in another div.

Here's a working example:

```js
//initialize select2
 $('#options').select2();

//initialize a global array to store the selected options
let selectedOptionsArray = [];

//select2 event to capture the selected value
$('#options').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  let selectedOption = e.params.data;
  let optionIndex = selectedOption.element.index;
  let optionText = selectedOption.text;
  let optionValue = selectedOption.element.value;
  
  //check if option already exists in the array
  let index = selectedOptionsArray.indexOf(optionValue);
  if (index !== -1) {
    //do nothing if option exists
    return false;
  }
    
  //else, add the option value to the array
  selectedOptionsArray.push(optionValue);
  
  //append the option to the desired element
  $('ul.results').append(`<li>
            <button type="button" class="remove-option" data-value="${optionValue}" data-index="${optionIndex}" title="Remove item">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> ${optionValue}
            </button>
          </li>`);
});


//click event listener on the appended to remove it
$(document).on('click', '.remove-option', function() {
    //remove the option from global array
  let findIndex = selectedOptionsArray.indexOf($(this).attr('data-value'));
  if (findIndex !== -1) {
    selectedOptionsArray.splice(findIndex, 1);
  }
  
  //remove the option element
  $(this).parent().remove();        //here, parent() refers to the li 
});

//fetch the current values
$('#fetchValues').click(function() {
  console.log(selectedOptionsArray);
  $('#values').html(selectedOptionsArray);
});
```

```css
select{
  display: block;
}

ul.results{
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.results li{
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="options">
  <option selected disabled>Select Option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="6">Option 6</option>
  <option value="7">Option 7</option>
</select>

<ul class="results">

</ul>

<button id="fetchValues">
  Fetch Values
</button>

<div id="values"></div>
```